# SSIS lookup two data flows (except? )

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup, except, dataflow

all.

I have two data flows flow1 and flow2 in ssis data flow task after multicast.

Flow 1 goes to ole db destination, and after insert it keeps only error records from it's error output. Flow 1 fixes the statuses of errored records.

Flow 2 keeps all the records of flow 1 before insert.

And now I need to fix the statuses of successfully inserted records. I see two ways of it and some questions in each of them.

1. Lookup flow 2 records to the inserted table and fix matched records as successed. But how to make it to wait until all the records will be inserted in flow 1 ? I dont like an idea of sleep in script component)
2. Match flow 2 records with error output from flow 1. This will make the flow 2 to wait till flow 1 insert all the records. But how to exclude rows of one flow from another?

Any ideas will be helpfull.
Thank you.
With regards, Yuriy.

Comment: Please add some screenshots of your package; I cannot picture what you are describing and have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure SSIS DataFlow idea:
* Do Left Outer Join with SSIS Merge transformation. **Note** - you have to sort both dataflows by the lookup key before doing the merge
* Filter out rows with Split Transformation, based on condition `ISNULL([column from error dataflow])`